# How can I access search box in OpenFileDialog with vb code?

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

How Can I Work With search Box in OpenFileDialog?
[image]

For example, I want to search files that start with 'Water' By Coding.

I Searched But I Can't Find Any Codes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. But if you typed in your search word in the search bar and no result occurred, maybe there are just no files which have "Water" in their name.

Comment: Not. You did not understand correctly.
I have a button in my program that when clicked opens OpenFileDialog and show all *.jpeg files that are in a certain path.
Now, I want to show only those photo files that have "water" in their names not all files.